# Select Top(n) from child table with single generated query

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

So I am trying to generate a query in entity framework that selects only the latest record from a child of a child. I am able to do that, however entity framework is generating multiple queries to achieve this which is impacting performance negatively.

This is what I have come up with:

```
_entities.Rentals.Include(r => r.CarClass)
                                .Include(r => r.Car).ThenInclude(x => x.CheckSheets).ThenInclude(y => y.ElectronicCheckSheetVehicleDetail)
                                .Include(r => r.Hirer)
                                .Include(r => r.Agent)
                                .Include(r => r.AdditionalDrivers)
                                .Include(x => x.Payments)
                                .Include(r => r.RentalAccessories).ThenInclude(y => y.Accessory)
                                .Where(....)
                                            ).Select(s => new Rental()
                                            {
                                                RentalId = s.RentalId,
                                                // More props
                                                Agent = s.Agent,
                                                Hirer = s.Hirer,
                                                Car = new Car {
                                                    // More props from this child
                                                    CheckSheets = s.Car.CheckSheets.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).Take(1).Select(a => new ElectronicCheckSheet() { ElectronicCheckSheetVehicleDetail = a.ElectronicCheckSheetVehicleDetail  }).ToList()
                                                },
                                                CarClass = s.CarClass,
                                                AdditionalDrivers = s.AdditionalDrivers,
                                                RentalAccessories = s.RentalAccessories.Select(a => new RentalAccessory() {
                                                    // More props from this child
                                                    Accessory = a.Accessory
                                                }).ToList(),
                                                Payments = s.Payments,
                                                AssignedDriver = s.AssignedDriver
                                            });
```

Everything works from below, the main objective was to to select only to latest record from CheckSheets and get the corresponding ElectronicCheckSheetVehicleDetail.

But when I run the Profiler I can see a lot of queries being run for something that could be achieve using joins, but I can't seem to get it right.

Queries generated are:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT {Column names}
FROM [Rental] AS [r]
INNER JOIN [CarClass] AS [r.CarClass] ON [r].[BookedCarClassId] = [r.CarClass].[CarClassId]
LEFT JOIN [Car] AS [r.Car] ON [r].[BookedCarId] = [r.Car].[CarId]
INNER JOIN [Hirer] AS [r.Hirer] ON [r].[HirerId] = [r.Hirer].[HirerId]
LEFT JOIN [Agent] AS [r.Agent] ON [r].[AgentId] = [r.Agent].[AgentId]
WHERE (([r].[PickupDate] IS NOT NULL AND (CONVERT(date, [r].[PickupDate]) = CONVERT(date, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())))) AND (([r].[Status] = @__GetDescription_0) OR (((([r].[Status] = @__GetDescription_1) AND [r].[IsOnlineCheckinCompleted] IS NOT NULL) AND ([r].[IsOnlineCheckinCompleted] = 1)) AND ([r].[OnlineCheckinMethod] = @__GetDescription_2)))) AND ([r].[PickupPoint] IS NOT NULL AND ([r].[PickupPoint] = @__branchId_Value_3))
ORDER BY [r].[RentalId]',N'@__GetDescription_0 nvarchar(4000),@__GetDescription_1 nvarchar(4000),@__GetDescription_2 nvarchar(4000),@__branchId_Value_3 int',@__GetDescription_0=N'Picked up',@__GetDescription_1=N'Confirmed',@__GetDescription_2=N'App',@__branchId_Value_3=10


exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(1) {Column names}
FROM [ElectronicCheckSheet] AS [o]
LEFT JOIN [ElectronicCheckSheetVehicleDetail] AS [o.ElectronicCheckSheetVehicleDetail] ON [o].[VehicleDetail_Id] = [o.ElectronicCheckSheetVehicleDetail].[Id]
WHERE @_outer_CarId = [o].[Car_CarId]
ORDER BY [o].[Id] DESC',N'@_outer_CarId int',@_outer_CarId=17789


exec sp_executesql N'SELECT {Column names}
FROM [AdditionalDriver] AS [r.AdditionalDrivers]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [r0].[RentalId]
    FROM [Rental] AS [r0]
    INNER JOIN [CarClass] AS [r.CarClass0] ON [r0].[BookedCarClassId] = [r.CarClass0].[CarClassId]
    LEFT JOIN [Car] AS [r.Car0] ON [r0].[BookedCarId] = [r.Car0].[CarId]
    INNER JOIN [Hirer] AS [r.Hirer0] ON [r0].[HirerId] = [r.Hirer0].[HirerId]
    LEFT JOIN [Agent] AS [r.Agent0] ON [r0].[AgentId] = [r.Agent0].[AgentId]
    WHERE (([r0].[PickupDate] IS NOT NULL AND (CONVERT(date, [r0].[PickupDate]) = CONVERT(date, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())))) AND (([r0].[Status] = @__GetDescription_0) OR (((([r0].[Status] = @__GetDescription_1) AND [r0].[IsOnlineCheckinCompleted] IS NOT NULL) AND ([r0].[IsOnlineCheckinCompleted] = 1)) AND ([r0].[OnlineCheckinMethod] = @__GetDescription_2)))) AND ([r0].[PickupPoint] IS NOT NULL AND ([r0].[PickupPoint] = @__branchId_Value_3))
) AS [t] ON [r.AdditionalDrivers].[RentalId] = [t].[RentalId]
ORDER BY [t].[RentalId]',N'@__GetDescription_0 nvarchar(4000),@__GetDescription_1 nvarchar(4000),@__GetDescription_2 nvarchar(4000),@__branchId_Value_3 int',@__GetDescription_0=N'Picked up',@__GetDescription_1=N'Confirmed',@__GetDescription_2=N'App',@__branchId_Value_3=10


exec sp_executesql N'SELECT {Column names}
FROM [RentalAccessory] AS [r.RentalAccessories]
LEFT JOIN [Accessory] AS [a.Accessory] ON [r.RentalAccessories].[AccessoryId] = [a.Accessory].[AccessoryId]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [r1].[RentalId]
    FROM [Rental] AS [r1]
    INNER JOIN [CarClass] AS [r.CarClass1] ON [r1].[BookedCarClassId] = [r.CarClass1].[CarClassId]
    LEFT JOIN [Car] AS [r.Car1] ON [r1].[BookedCarId] = [r.Car1].[CarId]
    INNER JOIN [Hirer] AS [r.Hirer1] ON [r1].[HirerId] = [r.Hirer1].[HirerId]
    LEFT JOIN [Agent] AS [r.Agent1] ON [r1].[AgentId] = [r.Agent1].[AgentId]
    WHERE (([r1].[PickupDate] IS NOT NULL AND (CONVERT(date, [r1].[PickupDate]) = CONVERT(date, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())))) AND (([r1].[Status] = @__GetDescription_0) OR (((([r1].[Status] = @__GetDescription_1) AND [r1].[IsOnlineCheckinCompleted] IS NOT NULL) AND ([r1].[IsOnlineCheckinCompleted] = 1)) AND ([r1].[OnlineCheckinMethod] = @__GetDescription_2)))) AND ([r1].[PickupPoint] IS NOT NULL AND ([r1].[PickupPoint] = @__branchId_Value_3))
) AS [t0] ON [r.RentalAccessories].[RentalId] = [t0].[RentalId]
ORDER BY [t0].[RentalId]',N'@__GetDescription_0 nvarchar(4000),@__GetDescription_1 nvarchar(4000),@__GetDescription_2 nvarchar(4000),@__branchId_Value_3 int',@__GetDescription_0=N'Picked up',@__GetDescription_1=N'Confirmed',@__GetDescription_2=N'App',@__branchId_Value_3=10


exec sp_executesql N'SELECT {Column names}
FROM [Payment] AS [r.Payments]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [r2].[RentalId]
    FROM [Rental] AS [r2]
    INNER JOIN [CarClass] AS [r.CarClass2] ON [r2].[BookedCarClassId] = [r.CarClass2].[CarClassId]
    LEFT JOIN [Car] AS [r.Car2] ON [r2].[BookedCarId] = [r.Car2].[CarId]
    INNER JOIN [Hirer] AS [r.Hirer2] ON [r2].[HirerId] = [r.Hirer2].[HirerId]
    LEFT JOIN [Agent] AS [r.Agent2] ON [r2].[AgentId] = [r.Agent2].[AgentId]
    WHERE (([r2].[PickupDate] IS NOT NULL AND (CONVERT(date, [r2].[PickupDate]) = CONVERT(date, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())))) AND (([r2].[Status] = @__GetDescription_0) OR (((([r2].[Status] = @__GetDescription_1) AND [r2].[IsOnlineCheckinCompleted] IS NOT NULL) AND ([r2].[IsOnlineCheckinCompleted] = 1)) AND ([r2].[OnlineCheckinMethod] = @__GetDescription_2)))) AND ([r2].[PickupPoint] IS NOT NULL AND ([r2].[PickupPoint] = @__branchId_Value_3))
) AS [t1] ON [r.Payments].[RentalId] = [t1].[RentalId]
ORDER BY [t1].[RentalId]',N'@__GetDescription_0 nvarchar(4000),@__GetDescription_1 nvarchar(4000),@__GetDescription_2 nvarchar(4000),@__branchId_Value_3 int',@__GetDescription_0=N'Picked up',@__GetDescription_1=N'Confirmed',@__GetDescription_2=N'App',@__branchId_Value_3=10
```

Is there any way I can force entity framework to do this in a single query? Preferably without using a Linq query?

UPDATE:

I did also try limiting the results in this section of the query without any luck, but I am not sure if that might be the key to solving my problem:

```
.Include(r => r.Car).ThenInclude(x => x.CheckSheets).ThenInclude(y => y.ElectronicCheckSheetVehicleDetail)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is really an answer but it's the solution I am going with for now. After doing some more research I found this thread:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12098

Basically EF evaluates the query and if it thinks it's required it splits out the query into multiple queries due to something called "dreaded cartesian product": 
One Include (Root + 1 child collection): 10 columns * 100 rows = 1000 data points.
Two Includes (Root + 2 child collections): 15 columns * 200 rows = 3000 data points.
Three Includes (Root + 3 child collections): 20 columns * 300 rows = 6000 data points.
With 12 Includes this would amount to 78000 data points!
Conversely, if you get all records for each table separately instead of 12 Includes, you have 13 * 5 * 100 data points: 6500, less than 10%

There is supposedly a balance at which the above becomes relevant(which is why they did that in EFCore 2.0.0). In cases where you are only selecting a small number of rows(say below 10) it is more efficient to select everything in one query. But once you select a lot of rows it becomes more efficient to select smaller sets in multiple queries.

However, according to the thread this has been updated in v3.0.0(we are currently on 2.2.1).

So my solution was to create a stored procedure as I don't think EFCore v3.0.0 is on long term support yet. But hopefully I will be able to upgrade it soon, which will resolve some more cases like this which I have